# Unix: Why am I getting, "integer expression expected"?

Tags: bash, unix

```
for arg; do
        [ -f "$arg" ] && x=1 && continue                                                                                                                                       
        echo "Not a File" >&2
done

[ "$x" -eq 0 ] && echo "No valid files"
```

I am getting this error: `[: : integer expression expected`

What is wrong with this? Is the for loop running in a separate process or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because 'x' is unset, so the comparison is between an empty string converted to an integer and zero.  It isn't happy about the empty string.

To fix

```
x=0
...loop as now...
[ $x -eq 0 ] ...
```

This has the beneficial side-effect of reducing the number of ways your code can break if someone exports the environment variable 'x'.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, use:

```
(( x == 0 )) && echo "No valid files"
```

In POSIX shells:

```
[ ${x:-0} -eq 0 ] && echo "No valid files"
```

or initialize your variable as Jonathan shows.